# select one item in one time in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to select one item on one time in angularJS.
Here is my code

```
<div ng-repeat="list in listgroups" >
    <ul ng-init="selected = -1">
        <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-class="{active:(selected == $index)}" ng-click="selected = $index;">{{item}} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Regards
Nauman

Comment: What is your question, how do we know what you want?

Comment: simple words I have multiple <ul> lists ( created by outer loop) I want to select only one item at a time form that particular list.

Comment: I added answer as per your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-repeat` creates new scope from current scope, so If you are using `selected` inside a inner ng-repeat will cause to create new scope variable for inner `ng-repeat`.

If you want to refer the parent scope from `ng-repeat` then use `$parent.selected` that will refer the outer scope variable of `ng-repeat`.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="list in listgroups" ng-init="selected = -1">
    <b>List {{$index + 1}}</b>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-class="{active:($parent.selected == $index)}" 
          ng-click="$parent.selected = $index;">
           {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/1204/)

For more information [**here is link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573954/pass-parent-scope-value-into-ng-repeat-loop-in-angular)

Comment: @9me Glad to help you..Thanks :)