# Why does the following $scope becomes blank inside this function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why does `panodataName` becomes empty inside the `$scope.addPanodata` function?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="panodataName" style="width:auto;padding:0;">
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:;" ng-click="addPanodata(pano.objectId)">Add</a>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('yoApp')
  .controller('addPanoCtrl', function($q, $scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, serviceUpload) {
    $scope.panodataName = ''

    $scope.addPanodata = function(panoId) {
      var Panodata = AV.Object.extend('PanoramaData'),
      panodata = new Panodata(),
      panoJSON = _.where($scope.building.pano, {'objectId': panoId})

      $scope.pano = panoJSON[0]
      console.log($scope.panodataName)
      console.log($scope.panodataName)

      panodata.save(json, {
      success: function(object) {

      },
      error: function(object, error) {

      }
      })
    }
```

I find it weird, because if I do:

```
{{panodataName}}
```

`panodataName` displays the value of `input` correctly.

**EDIT:**

Maybe it's because it's inside an `ng-repeat`?

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="panodata in pano.panoData">
```

Comment: You are not adding any values in the $scope.panodataName inside the $scope.addPanodata function.Once you add then only the value will not be undefined.

Comment: You do nothing with `$scope.panodataName` inside the `addPanodata()` except for displaying it in your console.

Comment: I thought ` ng-model="panodataName"` was supposed to add a value to `$scope.panodataName?`

Comment: I did something similar somewhere in the code: `<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="panoName">` `    $scope.addPano = function() {
      var Pano = AV.Object.extend('Panorama'),
   pano = new Pano()

      var json = {
 'name': $scope.panoName,
 'buildingCode': $scope.buildingId`

And the value is being retrieved inside `$scope.addPano`.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help [Difficulty with ng-model, ng-repeat, and inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714884/difficulty-with-ng-model-ng-repeat-and-inputs). And look at [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482)

Comment: Are you saying that when you enter text into the input then click the anchor `$scope.panodataName` logs `undefined` in your console, yet adding `{{panodataName}}` into the view shows the text entered into the input?

Comment: Please provide the whole html file. Maybe you can use Plunker(https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) for this purpose.

Comment: I can not figure the bug out, but about the second part of your question, I'm pretty sure that the problem is not related to ng-repeat. I've provided a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxgxRZ) proving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say youve got this logic within an `ng-repeat`. I suspect that is your issue.

What angular will do for each 'itteration' of an `ng-repeat` is create a new `scope`. So your `ng-model="panodataName"` is binding a property called `panodataName` to that local scope for that specific iteration of the loop, not to the global controllers scope.

Also if you add `{{panodataName}}` inside the ng-repeat then that will work and print the inputs text because its binding to the ng-repeat's child scope.

What i believe you want is to bind to the parent scope of the `ng-repeat`. This is where you actually define the `panodataName` property and also what your trying to log.

To do this you need to change your ng-model too:

```
ng-model="$parent.panodataName"
```

`$parent` is a global variable to that specific loop itteration's scope that points to the `ng-repeats` parent scope.

Hope that makes sense, ive added a fiddle demo-ing.

NOTE: There is one down side to this implementation, as each input is now bound to the same variable if you update one all others in the ng-repeat will update.

https://jsfiddle.net/j4txmzhe/

---

EDIT: Added proof,

This states that `ng-repeat` creates new scopes [directives-that-create-scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#directives-that-create-scopes)

Also a bit more Googleing brings up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573954/pass-parent-scope-value-into-ng-repeat-loop-in-angular#answer-16577545) SO answer where the comments describe why its a good idea to steer away from `$parent`.

Comment: `ng-repeat` creates new scopes but those scopes inherit from their parents. `ng-model` will work properly if there is a 'dot' in the name. Also you can also use `$index` from `ng-repeat` -- `ng-model="ref.panodataNameList[$index]'`.

Comment: @georgeawg Your correct i forgot that, i guess that's why allot of people prefer to bind not directly of the scope but of a sub-property.