# where do we use $parent in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was really confused with this example from angular documentation
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GWlDrDdH3u25JV4Whieb?p=preview) and [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

here I have removed `$parent` inside a ng-repeat but it is still working fine..?

why do we need to add that in ng-repeat because each `iteration` will have its own `$scope` and this will evaluate. why do we required previous or `$parent` scope.

Comment: plnkr link is invalid

Comment: scopes are all about accessibility of their relative properties while you're targeting nested scoping.

Comment: this i got from other question where do we use $parent in ng-repeat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573954/pass-parent-scope-value-into-ng-repeat-loop-in-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon what you are trying to achieve, if you are not using controller As syntax, you would need `$parent` to access the parent `controllers` scope in a nested structure.

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
    <div ng-controller="ChildController">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can access the parent `scope` as follows

```
function ParentController($scope) {
    $scope.states= ["Chennai", "Kerala", "Spain"];
}

function ChildController($scope) {    
}
```

Now you could do something from your view...

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ParentController">
    <div ng-controller="ChildController">
       {{$parent.states}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Now coming to case of your comment on a isolated scope, we could use `$parent` to access the property in parent `scope` but you could use the scope property `(@ , = , &)` where you can specify which scope properties you need to work with.

Comment: your answer cleared my doudts. but why do that punker example ng-repeat using $parent. its not required their right

Comment: see this example its not working with $parent or i was wrong http://plnkr.co/edit/scMSESFRj6QAwDvq4Xuk?p=preview

Comment: It should work, plunkr for me does not work properly here... here is a fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/zstL0so5/

Comment: ohh but in fiddle you have not added any cdn for angularjs

Comment: strange it works... i forked a normal angularjs fiddle... may be it has some references...

Answer (score 0):

$parent is often use when people don't really know what they're doing of with some kind of tricky directives.

Usually if you don't want to have to use $parent. Use dot notation :

```
$scope.toto = "titi";//not a dot notation
$scope.fields = {toto:"titi"};// dot notation
```

Having an intermediary object will make sure that you won't have any problems between scope that inherits from each others. This is a du to a limit of javascript.

Comment: can you give me an example for the tricky directive as you have mentioned

Comment: @santhosh: you would use the scope property of the directive to access the properties from the parent scope via (@, = and &) much preferred way.

Comment: @santhosh i just saw some people doing that on the net but in the end i never had to use $parent myself as long as i respected the dot notation. I can just say that it may happens with directives that inherits their scope from parent's scope ( **scope:true** in the definition of the directive).