# How to fix a Stripe's "Pay with card" button placed inside an ng-repeat tag in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, stripe-payments

I want to put a "Pay with card" simple Stripe button inside an AngularJS's `ng-repeat` tag type.

It is working properly when the button is placed outside the `ng-repeat` `div`, and opens the Stripe's model popup; but the popup does not opens when I put it inside an `ng-repeat` tag.

```html
<div ng-if(condition)>
  <form class="" action="/buyer/buyer/StripePayement? 
Amount=500"method="POST"> 
    <article>
     <label>Amount: $500</label>
    </article>
    <script src="//checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"
      class="stripe-button"
      data-key="pk_test_ryEeHLLIGikPwMiZdK7b0FNf00IbqsyXht"
      data-locale="auto"
      data-description=""
      data-amount="500">
    </script>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the actual code with the `ng-repeat` tag when the button is inside and when it is outside, and the error messages you are getting in the console if any.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an item inside of an `ng-repeat` the repeat has its own scope. You likely need to reference the parent scope with `$parent` like in

[Pass parent scope value into ng-repeat loop in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573954/pass-parent-scope-value-into-ng-repeat-loop-in-angular)